# Is $B_1$ and $B_2$ is open in $d_{\infty}$-metric?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

For $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2,\dots, y_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, let
$$d_p(x,y)=\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|^p\Big)^\frac{1}{p} 
\mbox{ for $p\geq 1$, and } d_\infty(x,y)=\text{max}\{|x_i-y_i|: i=1,2,\dots,n\}.$$

Let $B_p =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: d_p(x,0)<1 \}$ with $1\leq p \leq  \infty$ .

Which of the following are correct?

1. $B_1$ is open in the $d_{\infty}$- metric
2. $B_2$ is open in the $d_{\infty}$- metric
3. $B_1$ is not open in the $d_2$ metric
4. $B_2$ is not open in the  $d_2$ metric

My attempts: I know that a set $A$ in a metric space $(X,d)$ is open if for each $x \in A$ there is a number $r >0$ such that $B_r(x)\subset A$, but here I do not know how to visualize the diagram of open ball in  $d_{\infty}$- metric and $d_2$-metric.

Please help me and tell me the solution. I would be thankful

Comment: let say $d_2$ metric is a standard Euclidean one, while $d_{\infty}$ is a taxi-cab

Comment: im  not getting how can  i show B1 and B2 is open in d2 and taxicab metric@ dEmigOd

Comment: from you definition $B_2$ is an **open** ball in our standard human Euclidean space. It just should be open. Draw it on the piece of paper, pick a point and draw a small ball around it inside $B_2$. While you didn't ask, but a ball in the $d_1$ is a 45 deg rotated square. As all your balls are open in their respectful metrics, they are also open in the asked ones [draw small ball or square around any picked point].

Answer (score 1):

Hint for question 1: $B_1$ is open in the $d_{\infty}$- metric?

It has been shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2443026/which-of-the-following-inequalities-are-satisfied-in-given-banach-spaces) (the question is yours) that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the following inequalities hold
$$\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_1\leq n\|x\|_{\infty}.$$
Let $x_0\in B_1$ and let $x$ be such that $\|x-x_0\|_{\infty}< r$ for some $r>0$. Then
$$\|x\|_1\leq \|x-x_0\|_{1}+\|x_0\|_{1}\leq n\|x-x_0\|_{\infty}+\|x_0\|_{1}<  nr+\|x_0\|_{1}.$$
Is there any positive value for $r$ such that $nr+\|x_0\|_{1}<1$, i.e. $x\in B_1$?

In that case the set $B_1$ is open with respect to the metric $d_{\infty}$.

P.S. For $B_2$ the following inequalities should be useful
$$\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \|x\|_2\leq \sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty}.$$

Comment: thanks a lots @ Robert Z ,,,,but i have one doubt  question that,,according to my  previous question that u have been answerd,,,,,  |X|2 ≤  |X|1,,       ,     i mean  B1 is not open in d2 metrics   because B1 is not contained in d-2 metrics....am i right ? pliz tell me

Comment: @kalomlego $\|x\|_2\leq \|x\|_1$ implies that $B_1\subseteq B_2$.

Comment: @kalomlego Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Properties

Comment: thanks a lots  ,,,,once again ,,you are  my best friends @Robert Z ,,,i will vote up now