# How can we define an open set in $d_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I  am having trouble while solving a question,because i don't know the proper Definition of Open set in $d_{\infty}$ .I know the definition of $d_{\infty}$

> $d_{\infty}(x,y) = \max \left \{|x_i-y_i|  \right \}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$

Please help.

Comment: Same way as you define open set in any metric space. A set $U \subseteq X$ is open if and only if for every point $x \in U$, there is some open ball $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ centered at $x$ and contained in $U$. Such open balls are sets of the form $B_{\epsilon}(x) = \{y \in X : d(x,y) < \epsilon\}$ for $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: For $n\in \Bbb N$: For $1\le r\in \Bbb R,$ the function $d_r(x,y)=(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|^r)^{1/r}$ is a metric on $\Bbb R^n$ and generates the same topology (i.e. has the same family of open sets) that $d_{\infty}$ generates. The reason for the notation $d_{\infty}$ is that, restricting $r$ to values in $ [1,\infty),$ we have $\lim_{r\to \infty}d_r(x,y)=d_{\infty}(x,y).$

Answer (score 2):

In **any** metric space $(X,d)$ you define openness the same way. You define a ball of $d$ as $$B_d(x,r)= \{y \in X: d(x,y) < r\}$$

for any $x \in X$ and real number $r>0$. Then $U$ is open iff

$$\forall x \in U: \exists r>0 : B_d(x,r) \subseteq U\text{.}$$

But it's not very hard to show that $d_2$ (the standard Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^n$, so $d_2(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$ and $d_\infty(x,y)=\max\{|x_i - y_i|: i = 1,\ldots,n\}$ are equivalent, in the sense that any $d_2$-ball around $x$ contains a $d_\infty$-ball around $x$ and vice versa, so that the conditions for openness for these metric are equivalent too, and so they give exactly the same open sets.

More details can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267519/4280), e.g.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447353/is-b-1-and-b-2-is-open-in-d-infty-metric?rq=1 this is the question i want to ask ,the solution in this question is some complex for me so i am trying to make it simple.In this queston${B_1}$ is  open in $d_{\infty}$ but not on ${d_2}$

Comment: @gauravsaini $B_1$ is open in both $d_2$ and $d_\infty$ in that question (and in $d_1$ too, or any $d_p$ for that matter..). 1 and 2 are correct, 3 and 4 are not.

Comment: That's why i am confused here.But this question was asked in national level entrance exam .

Comment: @gauravsaini You have to choose which statements are correct, and I'm right here. two are correct and two are false. That is the correct answer. What is **your** source for the supposedly correct answers? What entrance exam? For entering a master's program?

Comment: okkk now i got this.

Answer (score 1):

Because $d_\infty$ is in fact normable, and all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, so open sets in the $d_\infty$-topology are the open sets in euclidean topology.

Comment: okk i got this ,but if somehow we change the domain does it effect the equivalency?

Comment: norms are not necessarily equivalent if $\mathbb R^n$ is replaced by infinite dimensional space

Comment: one more question

Comment: if set is not open in $d_2$ does it still open in $d_{\infty}$

Comment: @gauravsaini If a set is not open in $d_2$ then it is not open in $d_\infty$ and vice versa. That is what equivalence of metrics means.